# What are the $5$ different combinations of $4$ numbers that can add to $8, 9, 10$ or $11$?

Tags: problem-solving

There are $5$ combinations of $4$ numbers from $1-9$. If you write these on two coins, so there are $2$ numbers on each coin. Then you flip the coin. The sum of the two numbers add to $8,9,10,$ or $11.$

In other words, you can combine $2$ numbers to make $8,9,10,$ or $11.$

What are the combinations

Comment: What have you tried?  A little trial and error should give the answer, though since coins have two sides, I suspect there are only $4$ possible pairs rather than $5$.

Comment: @Henry I have tried trial and error, but I am missing the last two. Also, There are 5 _combinations_ not _pairs_ that add to the numbers

Comment: 1/2,7/9 or 1/3,7/8 or 2/4,6/7 or 2/3,6/8 or 3/4,5/7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let one coin have numbers $a$ and $b$ with $a<b$; and the other coin, $c$ and $d$ with $c<d$.

We then need $a+c=8$ and $b+d=11$.  Also $a+d$ is $9$ or $10$, and $b+c$ is respectively $10$ or $9$.  Without loss of generality, assume that $a+d=9$, and so $b+c=10$.

Solving the system $\left\{\begin{array}{c}a+c=8\\
a+d=9\\ b+c=10\\b+d=11 \end{array}\right.$

with the constraints that $a,b,c,d$ are different integers from $1$ to $9$, should give you all the possibilities. (Note that once a value of say $a$ is chosen, the other values are all determined.)